# Why is my SWR call getting hit before my Auth token is set by NextAuth + AuthRoute?

Tags: next.js, axios, next-auth, http-status-code-401, swr

I'm testing out some possible new data fetching setups for my current project at work. I think I'd like to use SWR, but I'm currently running into one pretty critical issue that kept causing my app to instantly redirect me to the sign in page. The basic setup is this:

I have a NextJS app with NextAuth setup for authentication. I use an AuthRoute component coupled with an Axios response interceptor to make sure nobody sees content while not authenticated. The auth route is a pretty commonly seen setup that just shows some waiting text while loading the NextAuth session, but I also use it to setup my Axios instance with a default header for my auth token. Then inside some child components / pages underneath the auth route I'm trying to setup the new SWR usage to get data from my backend AFTER the auth token is set for the axios fetcher. I would expect the flow to be Sign In page -> Authenticate -> AuthRoute sets token -> AuthRoute shows Children -> Child Page fetches with SWR, but for some reason I keep having the first get request come back as a 401. Here's the relevant code

[...nextAuth.tsx]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { api, setToken } from 'services/api/apiConnector';

const options = (req, res) => ({
providers: [
  CredentialsProvider({
    id: 'credentials',
    name: 'Login',
    credentials: {
      username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text', placeholder: 'jsmith' },
      password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
    },
    authorize: async (credentials) => {
      const { username, password } = credentials;

      try {
        // Retreive credentials from passed in data
        const {
          data: authData,
          headers: authHeaders,
        }: AxiosResponse<unknown, any> = await api.post(
          `my url`,
          {
            username: `${username}`,
            password: `${password}`,
          },
        );
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', authHeaders['set-cookie']);
        // store and check that auth token is valid

        const accessToken = authData.accessToken;
        if (!accessToken) {
          return { Error: 'No access token found in response' };
        }

        //This is a test call that I don't think should even be needed
        //Since setToken is called in AuthRoute 
        setToken(authData.accessToken);
        console.log('Access Token: ', accessToken);
        const { data: userData }: AxiosResponse<unknown, any> =
          await axios.get(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_HOST}/inferno/v1/users/me/`,
            {
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
              withCredentials: true,
            },
          );

        console.log(userData);
        if (!userData) {
          return null;
        }
        let finalResult = {
          accessToken: accessToken,
          ...userData,
        };
        return finalResult;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return { Error: 'Invalid credentials' };
      }
    },
  }),
],
secret: '<Secret Here>',
session: {
  strategy: 'jwt',
  cookieName: 'cookie_name',

  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 4, // 4 hours
},
jwt: {
  cookieName: 'cookie_name',
},
cookies: {
  csrfToken: {
    name: `csrftoken`,
    options: {
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: 'None',
      path: '/',
      secure: true,
    },
  },
},
callbacks: {
  async jwt({ token, user }) {
    if (user) {
      if (user.Error) {
        console.log('Error HERE: ', user.Error);
        return { Error: user.Error };
      }
      console.log('User in JWT:', user);
      const { accessToken, ...rest } = user;
      token.user = rest;
      token.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    return token;
  },

  async session({ session, token }) {
    if (token.Error) {
      return { Error: token.Error };
    }

    session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
    session.user = token.user;

    return session;
  },
},
pages: {
  signIn: '/auth/login',
  signOut: '/auth/login',
  error: '/auth/login',
  // newUser: '/auth/register',
},
});

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options(req, res));
```

apiConnector.tsx

```
const responseErrorHandler = (error) => {
  if (error.response?.status === 401) {
    console.log('Error: 401 Unauthorized. Redirecting to Login');

    // window.location.href = '/auth/logout';
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
};

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${urls[process.env.NODE_ENV]}`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  withCredentials: true,
});

api.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => responseErrorHandler(error),
);

const setToken = (token) => {
  console.log('setting token to ', token);
  api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
};

export { api, setToken, responseErrorHandler };
```

AuthRoute.tsx

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { setToken } from 'services/api/apiConnector';

const AuthRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession({ required: true });
  const userExists = !!session?.user;
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status !== 'loading' && !userExists) {
      router.push('/auth/login');
    }
    else if (userExists){
      // The setToken call that allows the Axios API to set a default auth header 
      setToken(session.accessToken)
    }
  }, [status, userExists, router, session?.accessToken]);

  if (status === 'loading' || !userExists) {
    return <div>Waiting</div>;
  }

  return children;
};

export default AuthRoute;
```

useFetch.tsx
I separated the SWR call fetch logic into another file for clarity

```
import { api } from 'services/api/apiConnector';
import useSWR from 'swr';
const fetcher = (url) => {
  api
    .get(url, {
      withCredentials: true,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      return res.data;
    });
};

export function useFetchQuotes(
  session,
  filters,
  paginationModel = { page: 0, pageSize: 10 },
) {
  console.log('useFetchQuotes', session);

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(
    session.data.accessToken
      ? `url goes here`
      : null,
    fetcher,
  );

  // This is placeholder
  let count = 5;

  return { data, error, isLoading, count };
}
```

QuoteList.tsx
The file I call the useFetchQuotes function from

```
Imports here...

const QuoteListTemplate: React.FC<any> = (pageProps) => {
  // Get our session from the app's context
  const session = useSession();

  // Get the dispatch function from our redux store
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

...

  // Create pagination state
  const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = React.useState({
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 10,
  });

  const headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.data?.access_token}` };

  // load data and other values from custom fetch hook
  const { data, isLoading, count } = useFetchQuotes(
    session,
    filterModel,
    paginationModel,
  );

... return stuff here
}
```

Finally, you can see in this image how the first time it calls the api it gets a 401, but then shortly after it properly calls with the token set [image]

Thanks much for any assistance in figuring out why it keeps triggering a 401 first.